# How do I import data from a text file into a postgres database?

Tags: postgresql, csv, text, import

I've created a table that has two columns: both varchars for numbers. 
My text file also has two columns, separated by commas.

Here's the command I'm using (italics used to distinguish from syntax):

```
COPY *table_name*
FROM '*/C:/Users/username/Desktop/filename.txt*' 
DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

I'm getting this error:
 ERROR: "COPY FROM 'filename'..." not currently supported

Everywhere I read says that I need to use the COPY FROM command, yet the error says it's not supported. 
I've tried changing forward slashes to backslashes and double backslashes as well.

Comment: Are you logged in as a superuser? (postgres user)

Comment: To whom are you issuing that command?  Your tags do not indicate a client program.  Also, what versions are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Here I think you forget to add Table Name between **COPY FROM** . it should be **COPY TABLE_NAME FROM**

Below is the working Example for it:

```
 CREATE TABLE master
    (
      master_id serial NOT NULL,
      master_name character varying,
      CONSTRAINT master_pkey PRIMARY KEY (master_id),
      CONSTRAINT unique_master UNIQUE (master_name)
    )
    WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
    );
    ALTER TABLE master
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

- Demo.csv

1,master01

2,master02

SQL to COPY from CSV file to master Table :

```
 COPY master FROM 'D:\demo.csv'  DELIMITER AS ',';
```

> Note: In many cases if you put your CSV file in C:\ than it will give
>   Access denied error. so I put this in D:\